# Error Installing ROS indigo on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS indigo on Ubuntu 15.10. I am following the tutorials given here:

```
 http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
```

When I enter the command

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

I get the error

```
"Unabe to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full"
```

I thought there was something wrong with sources.list file but when I opened it in gedit, the restricted, universe , and multiverse lines are already uncommented. I managed to follow all the steps from 1.1 to 1.4 up until i had to enter

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Which gives me the error mentioned above. Please advise!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220167/error-installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-15.10/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2015-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In installation page of the wiki, it states;

> Setup your computer to accept software
> from packages.ros.org. ROS Indigo ONLY
> supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty
> (14.04) for debian packages.

Therefore you may not be able to install debian packages on 15.10

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2015-10-30**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/220064/ros-on-ubuntu-wily/
The answer on this post says "You can always try building ROS from source if you are stuck on 15.10.". Do you know what this means?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-10-30**:
As it tells in that answer, instead on installing ROS using debian package, you can download the source code and build packages on your operating system. Details are here: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-12-18**:
I've succeeded building some part of ROS Indigo on 15.10, That doesn't mean anything will work, but at least the core stuff works. If you'd need to satisfy some dependency that doesn't have a package in 15.10, you may try playing with `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d` and create your own dep mapping.